# CSS3 radial-gradient warning

Tags: html, css, gradient, radial-gradients

Looking at some old code, i am getting an warning about some old CSS,

```
warning Webkit only supports pixels for the start and end stops for radial gradients. Got: 50%
```

The css here is on `background-image` which comes from `Compass` i believe: `radial-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.07), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 50%)`

What would this be in the new syntax?, i see the first two arguments are colours and the third is a percentage for the gradient i believe, [w3 schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp)
 has a different syntax compared to [some other places](http://www.broken-links.com/2012/06/26/the-new-radial-gradient-syntax/).

I tried parsing it through a CSS linter, but i would need to convert it from sass -> scss -> css

I tried the conversion and i get `unknown mixin header-image` and i have tried the `scss-lint` gem but it seems it won't do sass. Sorry if this seems like a stupid question, i just cant seem to find a decent explanation of what i should do. And my front end knowledge is very limited.

*Note - full sass section*

```
header#header
  background: url("../images/bg0.png") no-repeat 50% 29% rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)
  margin-bottom: 80px
  padding-top: 70px
  > .wrapper
      position: relative
      @include background-image(radial-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.07), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 50%))
```

Comment: There is absolutely nothing wrong with that syntax provided. Webkit will produce a circular radial gradient. (You can look at [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32143108/resize-the-radius-of-a-centred-radial-gradient/32145495#32145495) for a brief explanation on what the parameters mean).

Comment: Yeah the gradient is produced, but the warnings pop up everywhere.